# Translating will would

Tags: traducción, subjuntivo, condicional

I'm learning English and my native language is Spanish.
I've recently come across some phrases that are giving me trouble. Here they are, as well as their possible translations in Spanish. Note that even in Spanish I wonder which of these sentences are correct and which are not.

> I decide today that he will work tomorrow.
> Decido hoy que él trabajará mañana.
> Decido hoy que él trabaje mañana.

> I decided yesterday that he will work tomorrow.
> Decidí ayer que él trabajará mañana.
> Decidí ayer que él trabaje mañana.

> I decided yesterday that he would work tomorrow.
> Decidí ayer que él trabajaría mañana.
> Decidí ayer que él trabajara mañana.

> I decided yesterday that he would work the next day.
> Decidí ayer que él trabajaría el día siguiente.
> Decidí ayer que él trabajara el día siguiente.

> I decide today to work tomorrow
> Decido hoy trabajar mañana.

> I decided yesterday to work tomorrow.
> Decidí ayer trabajar mañana.

> Yesterday, I decided him to work tomorrow.
> Ayer lo decidí a que trabaje (o trabajara) mañana.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: There are two separate questions here.  The first is what does the English mean?
The second is how do you say the same thing in Spanish?

Comment: It seems odd to say "I decided yesterday that he would work the next day" becuase the next day after yesterday is today so you would say "I decided yesterday that he would work today".

Comment: We don't translate from Spanish to English here. "I decided him" is not grammatical. There are too many questions here.

Comment: [This](https://writingexplained.org/will-vs-would-difference) might help. IMHO phrase 2 is incorrect (‘will’ doesn’t follow the past tense). The final phrase is just wrong, ‘decided him’ sounds like something translated word for word from Spanish, it is not correct in English.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, si hablás español no hay necesidad de formular la pregunta en inglés. Por otra parte, este sitio es de español y por lo tanto sólo te voy a responder lo que está en español; las oraciones en inglés vas a tener que ir a consultarlas en el sitio que sea pertinente. Algunas observaciones gramaticales y de estilo:

**Sobre la posición del adverbio**: como en estas expresiones el mismo suele ser más importante que el verbo, se prefiere colocarlo al principio; de esta forma suena mucho más natural. *Ayer/hoy decidí* mejor que *decidí hoy/ayer*.

**Sobre omitir el pronombre**: En inglés es obvio por qué no se puede. Pero, ¿realmente es necesario incluír el pronombre ‘él’ en cada una de tus frases?

**Sobre el uso de ‘decido’**: el verbo en presente se prefiere para decisiones que se acaban de tomar. Pero si ya pasó un tiempo es mejor usarlo en pasado, incluso si la decisión de tomó hoy. Esto puede ser diferente en inglés, revisalo.

**Sobre 'decidir trabajar'**: *Decidí que voy/va a trabajar* es más natural que *decidí trabajar*.

**Sobre la conjugación del verbo en la cláusula subordinada**: Casi todas las que presentás son correctas. Tu problema probablemente sea que te confunden los nombres que aparecen en una tabla de conjugaciones pero no hay una asociación unívoca perfecta entre el tiempo del nombre de la conjugación y el tiempo real. Reflexioná sobre todo esto un rato. Las frases incorrectas o dudosas son:

> *Decidí ayer que él trabajara mañana.

> *Decidí ayer que él trabajara el día siguiente.

> *Ayer lo decidí a que trabaje (o trabajara) mañana.

En las primeras dos está raro el uso del pasado del subjuntivo para este contexto. La última no tiene mucho que explicar: vos decidís *sobre* alguien, no podés decidir *a* alguien.

**En síntesis**: En lugar de traducir todo palabra por palabra, ¿no es más fácil pensar cómo expresarías esa misma idea en castellano? En cualquier caso, yo veo acá un estilo de redacción que exhibe a los idiomas como meras traducciones—en el mal sentido, porque buenos traductores sí que los hay—en lugar de verlos como modos de vivir.